# What if probability current is independent of position and time?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, probability

I worked an example in Griffiths to find probability current and then determine the direction of the flow of probability. As you can see the $J$ is constant value and independent of time and position $x$. Then how do I find out what direction the probability is flowing? In the solution it says $J$ is flowing in positive $x$ direction.

[image: WORKED EXAMPLES]

Answer (score 5):

Here you can imagine $J$ as a one dimensional vector. In this case it is positive, so it is 'pointing in the positive x-direction'.

In three dimensions this becomes more clear. Define $\rho(x,t)=\psi^*(x,t)\psi(x,t)$. Now $\rho$ satisfies a continuity equation
$$\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot\vec J=0,$$
where $\vec J\equiv\frac{\hbar}{2mi}\left(\psi^*\nabla\psi-\psi\nabla\psi^*\right)$. You can interpret $\vec J$ as the flux of $\rho$. It points in the direction of where the probability density is flowing. For a plane wave of the form $\psi=e^{i(\vec k\cdot \vec r-\omega(k)t)}$, you get $\vec J=\frac \hbar m\vec k$.

If we treat all the variables in $J=\frac{\hbar k}{m}|A|^2$ as classical variables for a second, we get
\begin{align}
J&=\frac{\hbar k}{m}|A|^2\\
&=\frac{p}m\rho\\
&=\rho v
\end{align}

This is identical to the fluid dynamics definition of flux. In other words, we can see a plane wave as a 'river' of probability density, where each point has a constant velocity. It is flowing to the right with velocity $\frac{\hbar k}{m}$, even though the probability density is constant everywhere.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So that means if 'J' would have been some negative constant value then probability is flowing in negative x-direction?

Comment: @SarikaHirpara Exactly